# object array positioning-LibGdx

Tags: libgdx

In my game,if I touch a particular object,coin objects will come out of them at random speeds and occupy random positions.

```
public void update(delta){
if(isTouched()&& getY()<Constants.WORLD_HEIGHT/2){
         setY(getY()+(randomSpeed * delta));
         setX(getX()-(randomSpeed/4 * delta));
         }
  }
```

Now I want to make this coins occupy positions in some patterns.Like if 3 coins come out,a triangle pattern or if 4 coins, rectangular pattern like that.

I tried to make it work,but coins are coming out and moved,but overlapping each other.Not able to create any patterns.
patterns like:
 [image][image]

This is what I tried

```
int a = Math.abs(rndNo.nextInt() % 3)+1;//no of coins
        int no =0;

        float coinxPos = player.getX()-coins[0].getWidth()/2;
        float coinyPos = player.getY();
        int minCoinGap=20;
        switch (a) {
        case 1:
            for (int i = 0; i < coins.length; i++) {
                if (!coins[i].isCoinVisible() && no < a) {
                    coins[i].setCoinVisible(true);

                    coinxPos = coinxPos+rndNo.nextInt()%70;
                    coinyPos = coinyPos+rndNo.nextInt()%70;
                    coins[i].setPosition(coinxPos, coinyPos);
                    no++;
                }
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            for (int i = 0; i < coins.length; i++) {
                if (!coins[i].isCoinVisible() && no < a) {
                    coins[i].setCoinVisible(true);
                    coinxPos = coinxPos+minCoinGap+rndNo.nextInt()%70;
                    coinyPos = coinyPos+rndNo.nextInt()%150;
                    coins[i].setPosition(coinxPos, coinyPos);
                    no++;
                }
            }
           break:
          ......
          ......
          default:
            break;
```

may be this is a simple logic to implement,but I wasted a lot of time on it and got confused of how to make it work.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sin and cos to get the points each coin should be from the object. This example will create 3 coins around the exploding object.

```
    explodedItems = new Array<Vector2>(); // array to hold coin positions
    Vector2 explodingObject = new Vector2(10,10); // object location that has coins explode from it
    int amountOfItemsToExplode = 3; // amount of items to explode out
    int distance = 5;
    float angleIncrement = 2 * PI / amountOfItemsToExplode;
    // use sin+cos to get points coins explode from
    for(float i = 0; i < amountOfItemsToExplode; i++){
        float x = (float) Math.sin(i * angleIncrement) + explodingObject.x;
        float y = (float) Math.cos(i * angleIncrement) + explodingObject.y;
        explodedItems.add(new Vector2(x*distance,y*distance));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want to make this coins occupy positions in some patterns.Like if 3 coins come out,a triangle pattern or if 4 coins, rectangular pattern like that.

For this, I'll use a circle:

1. Use a random number as the radius
2. Let's say you have `x` coins, the position of each one can be calculated like this:

   ● `new Vector2(cos(i * (360 / NumberOfCoins) + Offset) * Radius, sin(i * (360 / NumberOfCoins) + Offset) * Radius);`

whereas `Offset` means how much to rotate the whole thing (can be used for more randomization and is in degrees) and `i` counts from 0 to `NumberOfCoins - 1`

Final Note: I'm not familiar with `libgdx` so the code I've written may need to be changed but the logic behind it is the same

Comment: Wow, the question was asked in 2017?? didn't notice that